# How to change the language on date and time stamp in MS Word for Max 2011?

Tags: macos, ms-office, language, app-store-connect

I am using MS Office 2011 for Mac on Macbook air with OSX 10.9.4. In the comment balloon the date and time stamp shows some different language after date. I have added the screenshot of Word document below. How to change it to English? The language in both Word and system preferences is already set to English.
[image: Comment ballon with different language in MS Word]

Answer (score 1):

Head over `System Preferences » Language & Region` and make sure you don’t use **Chinese** for Calendar option.

[image: Language & Region Preferences]

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I have already set the language to English in system and word preferences. My calender is set to Gregorian and I don't know where to change the language in calender option.